# Implementation examples of 'Model-View-Controller' pattern in Java?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am looking for general coding examples of the MVC pattern in Java to help me better understand the best practices associated with it. I have done the basic google search, and read the Wiki lol. If anyone has further examples or comments they would be very much appreciated!!

:D Badpanda

Comment: As MVC is a combination of different patterns (Observer, Composite, Strategy) I would recommend to first check them out first, try to understand them and THEN try to see how they collaborate in MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Swing framework](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) is also an excellent example of an MVC architecture.

There are some subtle differences between Swing and other MVC frameworks like Spring. Unlike a web service where most model objects are short-lived and the controller is responsible for flow of control, Swing relies on long-lived GUI data that communicate updates using events.

Answer (score 2):

http://static.springsource.org/downloads/petclinic.doc

http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html